# Android Sliding gesture based tabs

Tags: android

Google docs app uses swipable gesture based tabs using which you can navigate to different tab/category.
How do we achieve this?
[image]

Comment: Any clue yet? I've been searching and all I found was a ripoff component that's not as nice. http://www.zylinc.com/blog-reader/items/viewpager-page-indicator.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This link to a google blog post might help](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+blogspot%2FhsDu+%28Android+Developers+Blog%29&utm_content=Google+Feedfetcher), just came out at the end of August and describes a ViewPager component which helps to swipe between Views

Comment: @taranfx: Do you know where could I find an example? Thank you.